# Why EF Core 3.1.1 slower than EF Core 2.2.6? Do you have same encounter too?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I tested by saving 10,000 records and retrieving 10,000 records. All are in new projects. No additional codes.

**EF Core 2.2.6**: Save 10,000 records: 1414.1892ms. Retrieve 10,000 records: 0.0003ms.

**EF Core 3.1.1**: Save 10,000 records: 5029.9279ms. Retrieve 10,000 records: 0.0069ms.

**Dapper**: Save 10,000 records: 4782.7224ms. Retrieve 10,000 records: 12.2705ms.

EF Core 2.2.6 and 3.1.1 Code

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        List<User> list = new List<User>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
        {
            User user = new User()
            {
                Name = $"User {i}",
                Age = i + 1
            };

            list.Add(user);
        }

        TestDBContext db = new TestDBContext();
        db.AddRange(list);
        db.SaveChanges();
        sw.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;

        string s1 = ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();

        sw.Restart();
        sw.Start();
        var s = db.User;
        sw.Stop();
        ts = sw.Elapsed;
        string s2 = ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
```

Dapper Code

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        List<User> list = new List<User>();

        using (var db = new SqlConnection("Server=SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=true;"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
            {
                string query = $"insert into [User] (Name, Age) values ('User {i}', {i + 1})";
                db.Query<User>(query);
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;

        string s1 = ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();

        sw.Restart();
        sw.Start();
        using (var db = new SqlConnection("Server=SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=true;"))
        {
            string query = "select * from [User]";
            var s = db.Query<User>(query);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        ts = sw.Elapsed;
        string s2 = ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
```

**EDITED**

Used EFCore.BulkExtensions for EFCore. Used SqlBulkCopy for Dapper. Run 3 times again.

**EF Core 2.2.6 Run 1:**
Save 10,000 records: 108.1211
Retrieve 10,000 records: 0.001

**EF Core 2.2.6 Run 2:**
Save 10,000 records: 75.7498
Retrieve 10,000 records: 0.0007

**EF Core 2.2.6 Run 3:**
Save 10,000 records: 49.9556
Retrieve 10,000 records: 0.0007

**EF Core 3.1.1 Run 1:**
Save 10,000 records: 320.7665.
Retrieve 10,000 records: 0.001.

**EF Core 3.1.1 Run 2:** 
Save 10,000 records: 67.0531.
Retrieve 10,000 records: 0.001.

**EF Core 3.1.1 Run 3:** 
Save 10,000 records: 71.3584.
Retrieve 10,000 records: 0.0018.

**Dapper Run 1:** 
Save 10,000 records: 99.0564.
Retrieve 10,000 records: 8.2078.

**Dapper Run 2:** 
Save 10,000 records: 36.2659.
Retrieve 10,000 records: 10.0161.

**Dapper Run 3**
Save 10,000 records: 36.8418.
Retrieve 10,000 records: 10.6243.

Comment: have you run a profiler to see where the hot spots were?

Comment: Could you share your demos?

Comment: Batch inserts should use `SqlBulkCopy`, not EF. As for the performance differences, what happens if you run the tests in a different order? I suspect your database server is the cause more than differences in EFC. What does SQL Server Profiler say?

Comment: For that matter, Dapper has an `Execute` command for bulk inserting things from an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @DanielA.White I didn't use profiler. never use it before.

Comment: @Asherguru that would be a first step to see what exactly is slow.

Comment: @HieuLe https://easyupload.io/asxoz7  TestBenchmark project = EFCore 2.2.6 and Dapper. BlazorApp project = EFCore 3.1.1. You need to change sqlserver address.

Comment: @Dai cool. changed to SqlBulkCopy. Dapper: Save 10,000 records: 75.4898ms Retrieve 10,000 records: 13.9859ms. faster bulk insert.

Comment: How many time you try for this results

Comment: EFCore.BulkExtensions has better performance bulk insert for EFCore. EFCore 2.2.6: Save 10,000 records: 69.7982ms. Retrieve 10,000 records: 0.0007ms. way faster than dapper in performance of both insert and select.

Comment: @AkbarAsghari One time. I know 2nd time and onwards will be faster. Just want to see clean and refresh first run.

Comment: Edited post. I changed code for high performance bulk insert and also run 3 times.

Comment: Search bulk record insert tips for get best performance like insert 100 record 100 record

Comment: Efcore3+ has bad performance related issues